# How to retrieve a specific field from a namedtuple, as a value from a dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x

The dictionary is called phonebook. It has the key of a name, which then leads to the value of a namedtuple. I receive 'NameError: name 'Contact' is not defined'

```
from collections import namedtuple

def add_contact(phonebook):
  Contact = namedtuple('Contact','phone email address')
  name = input()
  phone = input()
  email = input()
  address = input()

  contact1 = Contact(phone, email, address)

  phonebook[name] = contact1
  print("Contact "+name+" with phone "+contact1.phone+", email "+contact1.email+", and address 
"+contact1.address+" has been added successfully!")
  print('You now have ' +str(len(phonebook))+ ' contact(s) in your phonebook.\n')

def consult_contact(phonebook):
    ask_name = input('What is the name of the contact?\n')
    ask_info = input('What information do you need?\n')
```

Error is here

```
    if(ask_name in phonebook.keys()):
        print(phonebook[ask_name][Contact].ask_info) #The error is here.
    else:
        print("Contact not found!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    phonebook = {}
    add_contact(phonebook)
    add_contact(phonebook)
    add_contact(phonebook)
    add_contact(phonebook)
    add_contact(phonebook)
    consult_contact(phonebook)
    consult_contact(phonebook)
    consult_contact(phonebook)
    consult_contact(phonebook)
    consult_contact(phonebook)
```

Comment: I'd suggest to work out a better [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve), possibly avoiding user input.

Comment: It looks like you would like to have a `dict` of `dict`s instead of a `dict` of `namedtuple`s.

Answer (score 0):

`phonebook[ask_name]` is a `namedtuple` object and it has attribute of which is the value of `ask_info`.

so you need to access it using [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) as follows:

```
print(getattr(phonebook[ask_name], ask_info))
```

`getattr(obj, 'foo')` is equivalent to `obj.foo`